# MVC Routing to a Blog Category

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I already have a route in the `RouteConfig`, to redirect to the `Archive` Action when there is a year and a month :-

```
routes.MapRoute("Blog", "Blog/{action}/{id}",
new
{
    controller = "Blog",
    action = "show",
    id = ""
});
```

Now I wish to have another `MapRoute` that redirect to the `Archive` Action when there is a category, for example `Blog/Archive?catId=2`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: er - that route is for the `'show'` action?  Also - you don't 'route' query string parameters; because they're not part of the url path.  Query string parameters are usually mapped to parameters on the target action method.

Comment: Isn't it the same? You've only specified defaults in your route.. which means if it doesn't change, it will use `Blog/show`. To get to the `Archive` action, `Blog/Archive/2` should work.. where the action method accepts an `int id`.. without specifying another route.

Comment: Actually I did a mistake.  I was redirecting the Category to the same action as the Year/Month Action. I changed the Category to a different action and its working now.  I do not need the routing inside the RouteConfig I beleive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RouteConfig you can add

```
routes.MapRoute("Archive", "Blog/Archive", new {controller = "Blog", Action = "Archive" });
```

In you controller you can have this action

```
public void Archive(int catId) {
    ...
}
```

This will automatically map catId query string value to the catId variable.

Comment: Note: this route-mapping must come *before* the other (non-archive) route-mapping in global.asax for this to work. Otherwise `Blog/Archive` will look like `Blog/{action}`, and get caught there first.

Comment: Actually I do not need this Route Action since I am redirecting directly from the Partial View.  My mistake.  But could be helpful in the future thanks!